# How do I access my .plist with JXA (Javascript for Automation)?

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript-automation

According to the Script Dictionary:

> PropertyListFile Object [inh. File] : A file containing data in 
>    Property List format
>
> properties:
>    (PropertyListItem) : the contents of the property list file; 
>    elements and properties of the property list item may be accessed 
>    as if they were elements and properties of the property list file

and in Apple's [JavaScript for Automation Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW8)

> ... the returned object is an object specifier — 
>     a reference to the accessed property—rather than the actual value. 
>     To send the get event to the external entity and return its value, 
>     call the property as a function:

But I don't know how to correctly use the *object specifiers* I am returned, nor can I see how to provide the particular `plistPath` to the `PropertyListFile`. Here's what I tried:

```
let app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

let systemEvents = Application("System Events")
let plistPath = Path("/Users/iain/testing.plist")
let cats = systemEvents.PropertyListFile(plistPath).catsList

console.log(cats)     /* --> undefined */
```

I am trying to emulate the Applescript:

```
to getCats()

    tell application "System Events"

        tell property list file plistPath
            set availableCategories to value of property list item "catsList"
        end tell

    end tell

end getCats
```

This is the .plist file:

```
√ nodejxa % cat ~/testing.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>blogPath</key>
    <string>/Users/iain/WebDev/iainhouston.github.io/_posts/</string>
    <key>catsList</key>
    <array>
        <string>Blog</string>
        <string>Devops</string>
        <string>Drupal</string>
        <string>Formal Methods</string>
        <string>Parish Councils</string>
        <string>Scripting</string>
    </array>
    <key>scriptFilePath</key>
    <string>/Users/iain/bin/makepost.py</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to figure out how to open and read a plist with JXA myself, and it was not intuitive at all. The documentation on JXA is frankly terrible. I searched the dictionaries in Script Editor, but also made liberal use of the `properties()` method in Script Editor, which will show you all the properties of many objects.

I finally did figure it out for myself, and I think this will work for you:

```
let app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

let systemEvents = Application("System Events")
let cats = systemEvents.propertyListFiles.byName("/Users/iain/testing.plist").contents.value()['catsList'];
```

Results in the log:

```
/* Blog,Devops,Drupal,Formal Methods,Parish Councils,Scripting */
```